# How to get historical stock price data from interactive brokers API?

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I want to use IBAPI to get historical stock data. My code does not work and returns nothings. Can anybody help me edit the code? Thanks

```
from ibapi import client
from ibapi import wrapper
import datetime
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.common import BarData

# ! [socket_init]
class App(wrapper.EWrapper,client.EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        client.EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)


 #Build a sample contract
contract = Contract();
contract.symbol = "9005.T";
contract.secType = "STK";
contract.currency = "JPY";
contract.exchange = "SMART";


app = App()
app.connect(host='localhost',port=7497, clientId=3)
print(app.isConnected())
queryTime = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
print(app.reqHistoricalData(4102, contract, queryTime,"1 M", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 1, 1, False, []))
queryTime = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
print(app.historicalData(4102,BarData))


OUTPUT:
True
None
None
```

I tried to read the source code. But I found it is quite difficult to understand for me. Other posts showed the answer that appears not relevant to the newest api version.

Comment: anybody who can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54423878/2855515  shows the way to make a simple program.  Your program doesn't even start the message loop using `app.run()`.

Comment: @brian Thanks for your reply, brian! I will check this. I found many answers in field topic from you. I appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

`class App(wrapper.EWrapper,client.EClient):` I would only subclass `EClient` if I wanted to override any of it's methods.  I don't use python very much but it's like that in other languages.

Inside the `class App` you need to override the methods you are interested in like `historicalData`

After `app.connect` you must call `app.run()` to start it's message reader thread.  Once that thread takes control it will block in your program so you must do program flow asynchronously.

I will put numbers in comments so you see the flow.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.common import BarData

import datetime

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):

    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        #4 first message received is this one
        print("setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        #5 start requests here
        self.start()

    def historicalData(self, reqId:int, bar: BarData):
        #7 data is received for every bar
        print("HistoricalData. ReqId:", reqId, "BarData.", bar)

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        #8 data is finished
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqId, "from", start, "to", end)
        #9 this is the logical end of your program
        app.disconnect()
        print("finished")

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        # these messages can come anytime.
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    def start(self):
        queryTime = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")

        fx = Contract()
        fx.secType = "CASH" 
        fx.symbol = "USD"
        fx.currency = "JPY"
        fx.exchange = "IDEALPRO"

        #6 request data, using fx since I don't have Japanese data
        app.reqHistoricalData(4102, fx, queryTime,"1 M", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 1, 1, False, [])

app = EClient(MyWrapper()) #1 create wrapper subclass and pass it to EClient
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=123) #2 connect to TWS/IBG
app.run() #3 start message thread
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are very kind. Your help saves me a lot of time.