# Interactive Brokers API not storing historical price data into xlsx, how to resolve?

Tags: ib-api

I want to distinguish the historical price data for e-mini S&P500 (ES) by RTH and ETH sessions and store them into xlsx files. The xlsx files are only showing 1 row containing: "Date, Open, High, Low, Close" without the historical price data. I am subscribed to the proper CME data. Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd

class HistoricalDataApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
        self.rth_data = []  # Initialize rth_data attribute
        self.eth_data = []  # Initialize eth_data attribute

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        # Callback function to receive historical data
        if reqId == 1:  # Check if this is the request you made
            date = bar.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            if bar.time == "16:00:00":
                self.rth_data.append([date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close])
            else:
                self.eth_data.append([date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close])

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
        # Callback function indicating the end of historical data
        if reqId == 1:
            self.disconnect()

def get_futures_historical_data():
    app = HistoricalDataApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=0)  # Modify host and port as per your configuration

    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "ES"
    contract.secType = "FUT"
    contract.exchange = "CME"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "202309"  # Modify contract expiry as per your requirement

    # Request historical data
    app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, "", "3 Y", "1 day", "TRADES", 1, 1, False, [])

    # Start the event loop
    app.run()

    # Store data in separate arrays
    rth_df = pd.DataFrame(app.rth_data, columns=["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"])
    eth_df = pd.DataFrame(app.eth_data, columns=["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"])

    # Export data to Excel
    rth_df.to_excel("rth_data.xlsx", index=False)
    eth_df.to_excel("eth_data.xlsx", index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_futures_historical_data()
```

Added `print(f"Received historical data. reqId: {reqId}, Date: {bar.date}, Time: {bar.time}")` to see if the historicalData is actually being called. When I run the code, nothing shows up in the console output. TWS is open and API ActiveX and socket clients are enabled.

I also added print statements before and after app.connect, which was successful.

```
def get_futures_historical_data():
    app = HistoricalDataApp()
    print("Before connecting to API")
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=0)  # Modify host and port as per your configuration
    print("After connecting to API")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for `historicalDataEnd` before saving the data.

You ask for the data (possibly even before you have a connection) :
`app.reqHistoricalData`

And then you start the read loop :
 `app.run()`

And then you immediately make a DF with data not yet returned :
`rth_df = pd.DataFrame`

If you are having a problem with asynchronous programming I would suggest:

https://nbviewer.org/github/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/master/notebooks/bar_data.ipynb

Main docs:https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/readme.html

If you would like to see an asynchronous method:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502748/2855515