# Interactive brokers TWS API Python, how to get trading day info

Tags: python-3.x, tws

Interactive Broker's TWS software has a way of showing trading day information, i.e. if the exchange was closed for this day and if open what the trading hours where. See here: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=22063

How do I retrieve this information via the relatively new TWS API?

I could not find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: reqContractDetails will return a contractDetails object with tradingHours as a field, http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1ContractDetails.html#a2a6f950c506280e2f2d3904126a3349d .  Try some code and see if you need more help.  Here's a sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/42868938/2855515

Comment: Thanks!!!  That is it!  

Could you put that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3):

reqContractDetails(id, contract) will return a contractDetails object with [tradingHours](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1ContractDetails.html#a2a6f950c506280e2f2d3904126a3349d) as a field.

[Here's a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42868938/2855515)  of using the new API.  Just call reqContractDetails instead of market data.  There's a EWrapper callback for contractDetailsEnd that will be called when the API is finished sending data as there may be more than one contract.

Comment: Is there a way to get the same data but for the past? E.g. for the past 1 month?

Comment: @ZsoltSafrany Not that I know of.  Best to routinely save what you need.  I go to investing dot com and scrape the holidays and news events for my own historical calendar.  Exchanges also maintain a list of past holidays.  Not sure about one off events like 9/11 or Bush sr.'s funeral.

Comment: thanks for the reply. One workaround I found in the meantime with the IB API is to request historical data with bar size being 1 day and duration being X days. This will basically return the last X days where the market was open.