# Get SPY share price

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I have created a [demo](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1286) account, and I am trying to receive delayed quotes with the following code, but it failed so far.

```
import re
import ib
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from time import sleep

class Downloader(object):
    field4price = ''

    def __init__(self):
        self.tws = ibConnection('localhost', 7496, 9003)
        self.tws.register(self.tickPriceHandler, 'TickPrice')
        self.tws.connect()
        self._reqId = 5 # current request id

    def tickPriceHandler(self,msg):
        if msg.field == 4:
            self.field4price = msg.price
            #print '[debug]', msg

    def requestData(self,contract): 
        self.tws.reqMarketDataType(3)
        self.tws.reqMktData(self._reqId, contract, '', 1)
        self._reqId+=1

if __name__=='__main__':
    dl = Downloader()
    c = Contract()
    c.m_symbol = 'SPY'
    c.m_secType = 'STK'
    c.m_exchange = 'SMART'
    c.m_currency = 'USD'
    dl.requestData(c)
    sleep(3)
    print('Price - field 4: ', dl.field4price)
```

As I am working with a demo account, I have to work with delayed data, so that's why I added `self.tws.reqMarketDataType(3)` (see that [link](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/market_data_type.html)). My problem is that dl.field4price return an empty list for the `SPY` symbol which is impossible. How could I get the SPY stock price in considering the previous code? Did I make an error?

Comment: I don't know if ibpy works with delayed data.  I don't know if delayed data works at all.  I don't know if the demo account has delayed data.  I do know that the ticktype is 68, not 4.  The ibpy source code doesn't have this type in TickType.py (which you should be using instead of hardcoding 4).   IB has a new python API as of 9.73 which may be of interest.

Comment: @brian Yes, I knew they have a python API. Maybe you should show me a similar code with the IB API.

Comment: I was just looking at the docs and it says `Note: TWS Build 962 or higher is required and API version 9.72.18 or higher is suggested.`  I would need to update TWS to test this, so not now.  Just add the delayed line to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42868938/2855515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you figured it out yet, but IB has forced an upgrade so I'm using ver 963 now.  I just added what I suggested and added the delayed request to an old sample.  I used Canadian stocks since I'm not subscribed but maybe that doesn't even matter.

```
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper #just for decorator
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *
from ibapi.ticktype import *

class TestApp(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
        self.count = 0

    @iswrapper
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        print("nextValidOrderId:", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId

        #here is where you start using api
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "RY"
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.currency = "CAD"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        self.reqMarketDataType(3)
        self.reqMktData(1101, contract, "", False, None)

    @iswrapper
    def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    @iswrapper
    def tickPrice(self, reqId: TickerId , tickType: TickType, price: float,
                  attrib:TickAttrib):
        print("Tick Price. Ticker Id:", reqId,
              "tickType:", TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType),
              "Price:", price)
        #just disconnect after a bit
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > 10 : self.disconnect()

#I use jupyter but here is where you use if __name__ == __main__:
app = TestApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=123)
print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % app.serverVersion(),app.twsConnectionTime()))
app.run()
```

Here is part of the  output, notice you can use ib's enum type to get the name of the tick type.

`Error. Id:  1101  Code:  10167  Msg:  Requested market data is not subscribed. Displaying delayed market data...
Tick Price. Ticker Id: 1101 tickType: DELAYED_BID Price: 97.02
Tick Price. Ticker Id: 1101 tickType: DELAYED_ASK Price: 97.02
Tick Price. Ticker Id: 1101 tickType: DELAYED_LAST Price: 0.0`

It's 9:40 am as I type this so the market is open but It's not 15 minutes delayed yet.  The DELAYED_LAST of 0.0 would need to be filtered out.  I don't think I've ever seen a real time last of 0.0, so beware.

I waited to 9:45 and I received

`Tick Price. Ticker Id: 1101 tickType: DELAYED_LAST Price: 97.63`

right on time.

Answer (score 0):

as my development work was mostly outside RTH,
the type 4 (Last price) wasn't always available.
thus, i tried type 9 (Close price) as an alternative.
the whole information may be seen [here](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html)

alex